# Vuetify - How do I customize styles of option in <v-select>?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, material-design, vuetify.js

I'm trying to find a way to customize the style of `<v-select>` options. I want to provide different `backgroundColor` depending on options' value. All of provided `:items` will be fixed (always the same), so I need to find a way to either detect options via its specific text value or by declaring unique class/id. What would be the best approach for this? Thank you.

**Current Code:**

```
<v-select
   :items="[
      'This is yellow option', // Yellow background.
      'This is blue option', // Blue background.
      'This is grey option' // Grey background.
   ]"
>
</v-select>
```

**[HERE](https://codepen.io/kevinmnm/pen/qBNwXyQ) is a link to my desired outcome example.**

```css
.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.grey {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>Choose</option>
  <option class="yellow">Yellow Backgrond</option>
  <option class="blue">Blue Background</option>
  <option class="grey">Grey Background</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use slot [`item`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-select/#item) as follows :

```
  <v-select :items="items" label="Standard">
            <template #item="{item}">
              <span :class="[{'yellow':item.includes('yellow')},
                    {'blue':item.includes('blue')},{'grey':item.includes('grey')}]"> 
                      {{item}}</span>
           </template>

  </v-select>
```

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    items:[ 'This is yellow option', // Yellow background.
      'This is blue option', // Blue background.
      'This is grey option' // Grey background.,
    ]
  }),
})
```

[LIVE DEMO](https://codepen.io/boussadjra/pen/XWKQLgb)

Comment: You're amazing!